# Is it a good idea to override jQuery's $.ajax with a thin Cache layer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, local-storage

Will it be a good or a bad practice to override all ajax call in my Web App's JavaScript code with an "invisible" Cache layer?

It'd be something like (pseudo-code):

```
$.prototype.ajax = function(...) {
    if( requested URL can be found in localStorage )
        return dataFromLocalStorage; // as Deferred

    data = invoke original $.ajax;
    localStorage.setItem(key, data);
    return data; // as Deferred
}
```

I can think of one pro: no refactoring is needed for existing ajax calls, and one con: future developers will be unaware of this functionality, as it disguises itself as a regular ajax call.

What do you think? Will it be a good practice or should I avoid it?

Comment: You don't have to silently hide it, you could refactor the code into a plugin that when included makes the behavior apparent.

Comment: @JasonSperske - that sounds good!

Comment: Douglas Crockford calls it the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: Is your question whether it's good to introduce caching or whether it's good/bad to do it by overriding `$.ajax`? The last one I'd consider bad practice (use plugins, see above). The first one would be different – it really just depends on the use-case. But there are implications to consider.

Comment: My question was about overriding `$.ajax`. You're right about the use-cases, I didn't really thought make it as globally as seems from pseudo-code, I can, for example, test the URL and only if it matches the particular use case use caching. Nevertheless, still overriding `$.ajax`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not a good idea to override the default behavior of `$.ajax` like this. Other code on your page including jQuery plugins might depend on the default behavior.

It is likely at some point you might want to get the freshest version of some data, if `$.ajax` always caches to `localStorage` there will be no way to do that. This could also lead to future debugging headaches when someone working on the code (including you) can't figure out why their AJAX calls keep returning stale data.

It would be much better to just implement the caching in a separate function. That way when you see a call to something like `ajaxWithCaching` it will be obvious that something more that a plain AJAX call is going on.

Comment: It is a good point that other plugins might count on default behavior. And it is also a good point at some point we won't understand why data is stale. However, the latter problem can be solved by applying some "Cache Policy" depending on time, for example.
I do agree, like said above by Jason, things need to be obvious and readable.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be overriding the default behavior of anything! If you change the way `$.ajax` works, what will you do when you're using a lightbox plugin (or literally anything) which relies on the normal functionality of `$.ajax`?

*It would backfire terribly upon you.*

Instead, create your own function which performs the caching, and uses `$.ajax` normally.

```
var cache={}; // Your Cache

function getArticle(id,callback){ // Your caching ajax-wrapping function (requires a callback)
  // Require the arguments
  if (arguments.length<2) throw "getArticle requires id and callback arguments";

  // If the article is cached, pass it to the callback and return
  var cachedArticle = id in cache
    ? cache[id]
    : null;
  if (cachedArticle) return callback(cachedArticle,true); // cached=true

  // If that article isn't in the cache, perform an ajax call to get it
  $.ajax({
    url: "article.php",
    success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
      cache[id] = data; // Cache it!
      callback(data,false); // Pass it to the callback // cached=false
    }
  });

  return true; // reporting that we launched an ajax request
}
```

Then to use it, you've got a pretty robust little function.

```
var ajaxWasUsed = getArticle(8, function(articleData,wasCached){
  console.log("Got Article #8 "+(wasCached?"(from cache)":"(fresh ajax)")+":",articleData);
});
```